# git push overwrites changes on the remote repository

Tags: git, github

I encountered the following issue which I believed to be impossible when using git (the remote is on Github).

I pushed my changes to the remote, and this push overwritten some changes made by an earlier push (from another user) and added a duplicate class definition that was already on the remote (the result is a duplicate definition of the class).

I assume one of the following scenarios occurred:

- I did a `git pull` before any commit, which I *always* do and there were no  conflicts as far as I remember or
- (unlikely but possible) I forgot to `pull`, in which case I should have got an error message like I got when I tried to replicate the issue on a local repository:

**The message I would expect to see, but I didn't**:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to '../git_sandbox/proj1'
```

I really want to understand how did this happen, in order to avoid it in the future.

**EDIT**
As suggested by [@CodeWizrd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1755598/codewizard), the `reflog` shows 3 pull before my commit:

```
2ccc5bf HEAD@{3}: commit: put back the bug fix in Hf._SubCl.init_from_js that was overwritten
98d087e HEAD@{4}: pull: Fast-forward
1154c89 HEAD@{5}: pull: Fast-forward
3e8f4e6 HEAD@{6}: pull: Fast-forward
```

But I can't infer any new information from that...

Comment: `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second command, `git merge` by default*. So if you did run pull, you ran merge (unless you told pull to use a different second command). Merge could easily duplicate things without conflicts, because Git isn't *smart*, it just follows a bunch of simple rules. You should always inspect and/or test the result of any merge.

Comment: Good to know about the duplicating. But how come a line like `if a==0` was changed by the other user to `if a==0 or a==1`, and my push changed it back (with no conflicts during the merge)?

Comment: That one does not make sense on its own. With the actual repository and command sequence, I could explain it, but here I have to guess. Probably the most common cause of this is a merge run with `-s` and/or `-X` options. Another way to get this is to define a *merge driver* in `.gitattributes` and your config file.

Comment: BTW I suspect some are confused because you show an example of a rejected push. The text above this makes it clear(ish) that this is from a second, separate experiment, but some people might skim.

Comment: @torek thanks, I inspected the command sequence at my side but I don't currently have access to the other user's command sequence. I do see in the logs that he had merges with conflicts, but I can't see if the conflicts were resolved correctly. Anyway your explanations were helpful.

Comment: It is possible to compare someone's past merge with what you get if you repeat the merge yourself. This isn't something people normally bother with, but if you want to track this down: (1) check out the first parent of some merge by its hash ID. (2) run `git merge <other-hash-ID>`, resolve conflicts, and commit. (3) run `git diff <that-merge> HEAD` to compare the two merge commits' contents.

Comment: I did as you suggest: I checked out the parent of a commit that shows a conflict in `git whatchanged` and I merged with the next commit. But I don't get any conflicts.

Comment: Odd - you're sure the two tip commits were the same two commits that fed into the `git merge` that had a conflict? (`git rev-parse <merge>^1` and `git rev-parse <merge>^2`, in other words.)

Comment: That become too long a discussion... I'll update the question with the info. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`git push` does not overwrite changes that another user made in the mean time, the remote will reject the push.(**note** that you can delete files from someone else in another commit and push it. This will **not** be rejected but the old commit is still there, you can show it/rollback)

`git push -f` will overwrite the changes, no matter what happened in the mean time.

`git push --force-with-lease` will overwrite changes but it will be rejected if someone else pushes in the mean time.

See the comments on the question for the following:

`git fetch` downloads the state of the remote.

`git merge` will merge 2 branches together.

`git pull` will download(fetch) the state of the remote and merge it with your local state. If other peaple commited in the mean time, your local repository will be in sync with the remote after that and you will be able to push it without problems.

In **your case**, another person `commit`ed and `push`ed and your `push` was rejected because you don't have his commit in your timeline. You would need to `pull` in order to copy the changes there.

Comment: I never use the `-f` option. How come the merge had no conflicts? It's not practical to examine a 1000 lines code file after each merge.

Comment: A merge conflict **only** occurs if 2 peaple modify the **same part of the same file** and that changes are merged.

Comment: "and your push was rejected" - that's the whole point. my push was not rejected.

Comment: If git tells you that your push was rejected, that means that the push you are currently executing is rejected. That push will not overwrite anything because it is rejected but it would overwrite something if you would do a force push(-f)

Comment: please read my question again. the 'rejected' message you see there is what I expected to see, and what I saw on a toy-repository I played with in order to replicate the issue. In the real repository it was not rejected

Comment: The `pull` merged the remote with your local state and that resulted in the remote changes and your local changes being added. Maybe the merge deleted it. It should be in your commit history in any case.

Comment: The history will also show you the exact commit that overwrote that.

Answer (score 1):

There can be several scenarios which will lead to these results:

#### `pull`

As you mentioned you did not pull the latest changes from the repository.
   Git will not allow you to "add" code (`git push`) while your local branch is behind the remote branch

#### `rebase`

Someone else has "played" with the repository using rebase and modified your repository history

#### `reset`

Similar to `reabse` - your `HEAD` was reset = pointing to an earlier commit than your remote branch which again will result in local branch "missing" commits from the remote

---

#### `git reflog` to rescue

You can try and look at your `git reflog` history to see what has happened.
`git reflog` hold all the changes which were made on the `HEAD` and you will be able to see if you have pulled or not.

[image]

Comment: that's a great tip about the `reflog`. What I see is 3 pulls before my commit, see my edited question